# How to get the float with given bit-pattern (as int32_t) in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion

I need a fast way to obtain the `float` with a given bit-pattern (provided as `int32_t`). Of course, the compiler should optimise the whole construction away. Simple conversion does a cast and `reinterpret_cast<>` is not allowed ...

Comment: Why is reinterpret_cast not allowed?  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx

Comment: @JohnZwinck `reinterpret_cast<>` on the pointer types is allowed, but that does require a memory location. won't work with variable in register

Comment: @MarcGlisse does the union have to be anonymous? (I'm confused about strong alias rules)

Comment: `*(float*)&int32value`. Technically not portable, but in fact works everywhere.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm pretty sure that I have managed in the past to persuade GCC to break your code. But not necessarily when `int32value` is a parameter, IIRC the breakage I had was that the strict aliasing violation resulted in the source not getting initialized.

Comment: Beware that moving from `int` to `float` and vice versa can be quite slow on modern processors.

Comment: @SteveJessop There are two separate cases.  If you pass the two addresses (the `int32_t*` and the `float*`) to a separate function, where the compiler cannot see the cast (or the union), it doesn't matter whether you use `union` or `reinterpret_cast`; it will break if you turn on optimization.  If you do something like `*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&int32Value)`, and use the `float` immediately, the compiler _should_ get it right.  If it doesn't (and I too seem to remember some problem with g++ here), the compiler writer is being intentionally obtuse.

Comment: @SteveJessop - interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesKanze: the problem case I specifically remember was `float f = 1.0; int i = *(int*)&f;`. The initialization of `f` was either reordered after the initialization of `i` or else removed entirely, I don't remember which. I don't think that this is "intentionally obtuse", it seems natural to me that under strict aliasing, `f` could reasonably be treated by the optimizer as unused. A parameter is slightly different, but I can imagine a similar re-ordering where a register-passed parameter is never stored to the stack location of the variable.

Comment: @SteveJessop It's intentionally obtuse if the cast is visible in the same translation block.  If the compiler is doing enough analysis to see that `f` is not used, it can also see that the address of `f` was taken, and that this address was _immediately_ converted into another type, so its usual rules don't hold.  (The issue is different if the program holds on to both pointers, beyond the local block.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: maybe I don't understand the same thing by "intentionally obtuse" that you mean. You seem to be saying that optimizers are intentionally obtuse if they don't detect this case where people frequently violate strict aliasing, in order to protect that case from unpleasant UB. I'm saying that apparently GCC didn't contain the necessary special code to detect that case when I tested it. I don't think that was a decision made on the part of the authors of GCC primarily to vex you, I presume it's just how the liveness analysis worked out with strict aliasing assumptions in effect.

Comment: @SteveJessop In order to eliminate `f`, the compiler needs to do significant analysis.  It must see that that the address of `f` was taken, and it must determine what was done with it, in order to determine if it has "escaped"; if it has escaped, then it must be deemed used.  All that is needed is for the compiler to treat a type conversion as if the address has escaped.  In accordance with the original _intent_ of the C standard; the standard cannot define the behavior here, because of possible trapping values, etc., but the intent was that this technique work for type punning.

Comment: @SteveJessop (And just to be clear, my opinion with regards to the intent is based on discussions in the committee.  I'm not sure that it's apparent from the final wording.  IMHO, the final wording, neither in C nor in C++, still doesn't capture the real intent, since neither for `union` nor for `reinterpret_cast` is there any mention of whether the cast or union is immediately visible or not.)

Comment: @James: well, it's certainly not apparent to me from the wording in the standard that this is intended to work. Like you say, some text would be needed to explain under what circumstances it's OK to violate strict aliasing. Possibly it's not apparent to Pete Becker either, depending on what he means by "technically not portable" above. Maybe he means there's a strict aliasing issue like that I describe, maybe he just means because the representation of `float` is implementation defined. I'm prepared to believe that the GCC behavior I encountered was (in the opinion of its authors) a bug.

Comment: @SteveJessop Like me, Pete has participated in the standards committee; his point of view, like mine, may be influenced by discussions in the committee.  But it is clear that the standard needs work here.  The following (fully legal according to the standard) breaks with g++: module 1: `union U { int i; float f; } u; u.i = 42; f(&u.i, &u.f);`, module 2: `void f(int* pi, float* pf) { int r = *pi; *pf = 3.14; return r; }`.  If the aliasing rules are to be of any use, the compiler must be allowed to break this, despite the current wording.

Comment: @James: ISWYM, the standard should say that `*pf = 3.14` is UB in the case where it changes the dynamic type of an object. Or equivalent. Then you have to say something fairly wordy about how you can change the dynamic type of an object in a union provided that conditions hold sufficient for the compiler to work out that there's a union involved.

Comment: @SteveJessop That's about it.  It's not about changing the dynamic type, per se, but the fact that there are legal cases where pointers to different types can alias, provided the writes and the reads occur in the right order.  But it's basically just an example; the standard does need some sort of wording which requires the compiler to recognize certain aliasing, but lets it off the hook when the background reason for the aliasing is not visible.  I know that there was some discussion of this issue in the C committee, but I can't find anything in the latest C standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree with some of your points, not with the last one. The example of passing two pointers that alias the same memory is a clear violation of the strict aliasing rule and I don't have any problem with the code breaking. After all, strict aliasing means that the compiler can assume that both pointers refer to unrelated objects (BTW, a similar case is mentioned in the gcc man page when describing the `-fstrict-aliasing` optimizer flag).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I fully agree that the gcc compiler is *obtuse* (I had worse terms in my mind just a few hours ago) with its aggressive use of the strict aliasing rules, in particular: `int64_t i; i = 5; double f = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&i);` can and does get reordered into `int64_t i; double f = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&i); i = 5;`. While there are *two* pointers of different types, it is clear in code that they refer to exactly the same object ($X!@$ it is a *cast*!). Moreover, in the generated code there is a single register used for both operations (store 5 and load into fpu)

Comment: The fact that the language allows the reorder does not mean that in simple cases as this the compiler should not (as a quality of implementation) not be a bit more *sane*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Could you show me this in the standard?  It's the first time I've ever heard of it.  I don't have any problem with the code breaking, but I don't think the current wording in the standard allows it to break.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I rechecked the standard, and you are right in that I cannot find any reason for this not to work. The aliasing rules (3.10p10) talk about reading/writing from different types, but in that example, both operations are writes to different elements of an union. Still, ignoring the exact wording, my understanding is that the strict aliasing rules are there to allow that reorder inside `f`, although I had never considered that particular use of the union :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree with you entirely.  The current wording doesn't really express what I'm pretty sure was the intent: for strict aliasing rules to allow better optimization.  But I'll admit that I don't know too much how to word it to express what I think is needed: that the visible cast and union access "work" as someone who is familiar with the architecture of the system would expect, but that all bets are off if the cast or union is invisible.  The problem is precisely specifying what "visible" means here.

Comment: Maybe rather than "visible", what's needed is a concept of when two pointers of different types are "derived from" the same object, and allow aliasing via pointers with common derivation. It would be quite a tight definition -- pointer function parameters would have unknown derivation and thus aren't "derived from" the same object as anything else. So James's union example above would be UB because the pointers have no common derivation in module 2 (although they do in module 1). Meanwhile the `reinterpret_cast` could be given defined behavior (in the absence of trap representations, that is).

Comment: I think this definition of "derived from" would be similar to but different from the definition of "based on" that applies to `restrict` in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not reliable that the compiler will optimize this away, but it avoids UB provided that the value supplied really is a representation of a float (that is, it's the right size and its bit pattern doesn't hold a trap representation of `float`). GCC is at least sometimes capable of optimizing it away:

```
float convert(int32_t inputvalue) {
    float f;
    std::memcpy(&f, &inputvalue, sizeof(f));
    return f;
}
```

If the optimization is an important part of the question then the official answer is that there is no way to guarantee that an unknown compiler will make a given optimization. But this one is harder to optimize than most. It relies on the compiler "understanding" what `memcpy` does, which is a bigger ask than "understanding" what a pointer cast does.

Comment: +1 Used this successfully, with both *VC 2010* and *gcc 4.6* optimizing this into a simple load of the 32-bit memory into a floating point register. I even saw this getting optimized better than the `union`-approach, at least for the reverse `float`-to-`int` case (which made VC use an additional roundtrip from memory over float register to int register for the `union`-approach, probably due to the float assignment). In fact `memcpy` may seem like a heavy thing, but for such simple operands the compiler really knows what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The only fully portable method is to `memcpy` via a buffer:

```
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int32_t), "!!");
char buf[sizeof(float)];
memcpy(buf, &i, sizeof(buf));
memcpy(&f, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Usually the buffer can be elided:

```
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int32_t), "!!");
memcpy(&f, &i, sizeof(float));
```

Comment: @MarcGlisse direct `memcpy` (not via a buffer) is only defined where the source and destination have the same type (3.9p3), but it's difficult to see how a compiler could fail to interpret direct `memcpy` as intended.

Comment: @ecatmur What makes you say that?  Whether you pass through the intermediate buffer or not, the required semantics are exactly the same.  (Both are "undefined behavior", because the bit pattern in the source might correspond to a trapping value in the destination type, but you _are_ guaranteed to get the same bit pattern.)

Comment: @JamesKanze 3.9p2 gives copy into a buffer and back to the original object; 3.9p3 direct copy between objects of the same type.  I can see how to infer that copy into a buffer and to an object of different type is defined, but not for direct copy.

Comment: @ecatmur Except that §3.9/2 explicitly says that the results are
defined _only_ if the buffer is copied back into an object of 
the same type.  The two paragraphs basically make the same 
guarantee, the first for indirect copies, and the second for
direct copies.  The standard _cannot_ guarantee more, because
some legal representations of values of one type will be
trapping representations in another type.

Comment: @JamesKanze we're only interested in the case where an byte sequence is a valid object representation for both types; the standard *could* make guarantees in this case, yet it doesn't.

Comment: @ecatmur It's hard to say what it could guarantee.  It certainly couldn't guarantee what the value might be, since that depends on the architecture.  I'd like it to guarantee something as well, but I can't find any appropriate wording which would still allow undefined behavior if the byte sequence were invalid.